# R - predicting simple dyn model with one lag term

Tags: r, dynamic, regression, forecasting

I'm trying to predict a simple lagged time series regression with the dyn library in R.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856555/iteratively-forecasting-dyn-models) was a helpful starting point, but I'm getting some weird behaviour that I'm hoping someone can explain.

Here's a minimum working example.

```
library(dyn)

# Initial data
y.orig <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9)),n=10)
x1.orig <- rnorm(10)
data <- cbind(y=y.orig, x1=x1.orig)

# This model, with a single lag term, predicts from t=2
mod1 <- dyn$lm(y ~ lag(y, -1), data)
y.new <- window(y.orig, end=end(y.orig) + c(5,0), extend=TRUE)
newdata1 <- cbind(y=y.new)
predict(mod1, newdata1)

# This one, with a lag plus another predictor, predicts from t=1 on
mod2 <- dyn$lm(y ~ lag(y, -1) + x1, data)
y.new <- window(y.orig, end=end(y.orig) + c(5,0), extend=TRUE)
x1.new <- c(x1.orig, rnorm(5))
newdata2 <- cbind(y=y.new, x1=x1.new)
predict(mod2, newdata2)
```

Why is there the difference between the two?  Can anyone suggest how to predict my ''mod1'' using dyn?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `mod1` and `mod2` start predicting at `t=2`.  The prediction vector for `mod2` starts at `t=1` but its `NA`.  Regarding why one starts at 2 and the other at 1 note that `predict` merges together the variables on the right hand side of the formula and in the case of `mod1` we see that `lag(y, -1)` starts at t=2 since `y` starts at t=1.  On the other hand in the case of `mod2` when we merge `lag(y, -1)` and `x1` we get a series that starts at t=1 (since `x1` starts at t=1).  Try this which does not involve dyn:

```
> start(with(as.list(newdata1), merge.zoo(lag(y, -1))))
[1] 2
> start(with(as.list(newdata2), merge.zoo(lag(y, -1), x1)))
[1] 1
```

If we wanted `predict(mod1, newdata1)` to start at t=1 we could add our own Intercept column and remove the default intercept to avoid duplication.  That would force it to start at 1 since now the RHS has a series which starts at 1:

```
data.b <- cbind(y=y.orig, x1=x1.orig, Intercept = 1)
mod.b <- dyn$lm(y ~ Intercept + lag(y, -1) - 1, data.b)

newdata.b <- cbind(Intercept = 1, y = y.new)
predict(mod.b, newdata.b)
```

Regarding the second question, if you want to predict `mod1` then use `fitted(mod1)` .

It seems there is lurking some third question about how it basically all works so maybe this clarifies it.  All dyn does is to align the time series in the formula and then `lm` and `predict` can be run as usual.  For example, if we create an aligned model frame using `dyn$model.frame` then everything else can be done using just ordinary `lm` and ordinary `predict` and `dyn` is not involved from that point onwards.  Below `mod1a` is similar to `mod1` from the question except it runs an ordinary `lm` on the aligned model frame.  If you understand the `mod1a` `lm` and its `predict` then `mod1` and `predict` are similar.

```
## mod1 and mod1a are similar

# from code in the question
mod1 <- dyn$lm(y ~ lag(y, -1), data = data)
mod1

# redo it using a plain lm by applying dyn to model.frame
mf <- dyn$model.frame(y ~ lag(y, -1), data = data)
mod1a <- lm(y ~ `lag(y, -1)`, mf)
mod1a

## the two predicts below are similar

# the 1 ensures its an mts rather than ts but is otherwise not used
newdata1 <- cbind(y=y.new, 1) 
predict(mod1, newdata1)

newdata1a <- cbind(1, `lag(y, -1)` = lag(y.new, -1))
predict(mod1a, newdata1a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  However this doesn't really answer my question: why does mod1 above predict a time series with start = 2 and mod2 predict a time series with start = 1?

Comment: I have added some elaboration to the first paragraph.

Comment: Okay it's starting to make sense now.  Since I need both models to have a start = 1, I guess I'll have to come up with some hack to move the window back.  It would be great if there was an easy way to do this (e.g. an option to predict), so I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are any ideas floating about.

Comment: Have added code illustrating how to force `predict(mod1, newdata1)` to start at 1.

Comment: Thanks G. Very helpful and works great with the rest of my function.